# How do I compare the contents of a capture with another string in lua

Tags: string, lua, gsub

Suppose I have a string like so.

```
string = "This is just an {example} of a string. {Quite} boring."
```

At some point in the code, I want to use a function to replace the words between the curly brackets with something else. I prodded around in the manual, and came up with this solution.

```
function stringModify(a)
  return string.gsub(a, '{(.-)}', stringDecide("%1"))
end

function stringDecide(a)
  if a == "example" then
    return "excellent example"
  elseif a == "Quite" then
    return "Not"
  else
    return "ERROR"
  end 
end
```

Only that it doesn't work the way I want it. The if part, for example, treats variable a as a literal "%1", instead of the contents of the capture.

How do I make it so that the contents of the capture is compared, instead the literal interpretation of the "%1" string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do the whole %1 thing to pass the captures over to your function. [One possible mode of operation of string.gsub takes a function as an argument and passes it a string/array of strings representing the capture(s) every time it finds a match:](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html)

> The last use of captured values is perhaps the most powerful. We can call string.gsub with a function as its third argument, instead of a replacement string. When invoked this way, string.gsub calls the given function every time it finds a match; the arguments to this function are the captures, while the value that the function returns is used as the replacement string.

Taking this into account, you can **just remove a few characters from your existing code** so you pass the function rather than calling it:

```
function stringModify(a)
  return string.gsub(a, '{(.-)}', stringDecide)
end
```

and your `stringDecide` function will work unmodified, [as you can see](http://codepad.org/vXSN7Wct).

In your existing code, what you're wanting to happen is that `string.gsub` will call `stringDecide` for each match, substituting the string captured into the string parameter to `stringDecide` on each call, but what's in fact happening is that `stringDecide` is being called once with the literal parameter `"%1"` before `string.gsub` is even called, and it is returning `"ERROR"` as expected, basically expanding your `string.gsub` call in place to `string.gsub(a, '{(.-)}', "ERROR")`.

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as I wanted it to work.